# React Native Flex box, how to make middle view take all available space, given start and end items have fixed width

Tags: react-native

[image]

I'm reading the Flex layout in React Native but I'm still unable to make the Middle (white box) to take what ever available left (without fixed width, since different device will have different width). Also struggling to make the green box always go to the end.
How would I layout this?

Answer (score 5):

This can be solve by adding:

```
 flexGrow:1
```

you can take references:
https://demos.scotch.io/visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-flexbox-playground/demos/

Comment: That is React, not working for me in React Native

Comment: @visualSharp are u add, flexGrow:1 to whiteSpace 's  view?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using `flex`

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', height: 300, alignItems: 'center'}}>
<View style={{width: 40, backgroundColor: 'blue'}} />
<View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white'}} />
<View style={{width: 30, backgroundColor: 'green'}} />
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', width: '100%', height: 100}}>
    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', width: 40}}></View>
    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white', flexGrow: 1}}></View>
    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'green', width: 30}}></View>
  </View>
```

Setting `flexGrow: 1` works for me.